# How to retrieve items from a generic list in a type safe way

Tags: generics, kotlin

I'd like to put items in a generic container but retrieve them in a type safe manner.  The container will tag each item with a sequence number when it's added.  I tried to implement this in Kotlin but ran into problems in the `pens()` method.  Is there a way to use type information in a function argument to define the type of the return value?

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

interface Item
data class Pen(val name: String) : Item
data class Eraser(val name: String) : Item
data class Ref<out T : Item> (val id: Int, val item: T)

class Container<T: Item> {
    private val seq = AtomicInteger(0)
    private val items: MutableList<Ref<T>> = mutableListOf()
    fun add(item: T) =  items.add(Ref(seq.incrementAndGet(), item))

    fun filter(cls: KClass<*>) : List<Ref<T>> = items.filter{cls.isInstance(it.item)}.toList()

    // to retrieve pens in a type safe manner
    // Type mismatch required: List<Ref<Pen>> found: List<Ref<T>> 
    fun pens(): List<Ref<Pen>> = filter(Pen::class) 
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val container = Container<Item>()
    container.add(Pen("Pen-1"))
    container.add(Pen("Pen-2"))
    container.add(Eraser("Eraser-3"))
    container.add(Eraser("Eraser-4"))
    // the filter method works
    container.filter(Pen::class).forEach{println(it)}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> Is there a way to use type information in a function argument to define the type of the return value?

Yes. You can use [generic functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generic-functions) and [reified type parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) to accomplish this. You got it to work using a generic function. See the example below for an example using reified parameters.

### Discussion

Unfortunately [`filter`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index.html) only returns items with the original type:

```
fun <T> Iterable<T>.filter(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): List<T>
```

This means that you have to use a method that filters and returns a different type. It is tempting to try to use a method such as [`filterIsInstance`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index.html) to do the job. Unfortunately, in this case, the type is `Ref<T>`. `filterIsInstance` fails because T becomes an erased type, resulting in all items being returned. This means that you have to define your own version that tests based on the member variable type rather than on the whole type. My preference is to make this a function of the list rather than the container, like so:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

interface Item
data class Pen(val name: String) : Item
data class Eraser(val name: String) : Item
data class Ref<T : Item> (val id: Int, val item: T)

inline fun <reified R: Item> List<Ref<*>>.filter(predicate: (Ref<*>) -> Boolean): List<Ref<R>> {
  val result = ArrayList<Ref<R>>()
  @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
  for(item in this) if (predicate(item)) result.add(item as Ref<R>)
  return result
}


class Container<T: Item> {
    private val seq = AtomicInteger(0)
    private val items: MutableList<Ref<T>> = mutableListOf()
    fun add(item: T) =  items.add(Ref(seq.incrementAndGet(), item))

    // to retrieve pens in a type safe manner
    fun pens() = items.filter<Pen> { it.item is Pen }
}


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val container = Container<Item>()
    container.add(Pen("Pen-1"))
    container.add(Pen("Pen-2"))
    container.add(Eraser("Eraser-3"))
    container.add(Eraser("Eraser-4"))

    println("[${container.pens()}]")
}
```

With minimal effort, this approach allows you to do similar filtering anywhere in your code, and it is idiomatic Kotlin.

The inline function is a morph of the Kotlin source for [`filterIsInstance`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.1.3/libraries/stdlib/src/generated/_Collections.kt#L2213). The unchecked cast is unfortunately unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

Your `filter` method returns type `List<Ref<T>>` while your `pens` method returns type `List<Ref<Pen>>`.  Because you declared the `container` to be `Container<Item>`, the filter type is effectively `List<Ref<Item>>`.  You cannot set a `List<Ref<Pen>>` equal to a `List<Ref<Item>>`.

You can make `pens` return `List<Ref<T>>` (which might defeat the type safety you are looking for).  Or, for `pens`, transform the list with `map` to a `List<Ref<Pen>>`.  For example...

```
fun pens(): List<Ref<Pen>> = filter(Pen::class).map { 
    it as Ref<Pen> ) 
}
```

According to [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#unsafe-cast-operator), the `as` operator as used above is an "Unsafe" cast operator.  That's because `it.item` could be any `item` or subtype of `item`.  If `it.item` were not a `Pen`, an exception would be thrown.  But since you are filtering for only `Pen` items, it will never throw the exception.

Comment: The filter produces a list of Ref<T>.  Is there a way to cast Ref<T> to Ref<Pen>, rather than create new copies of Ref<Pen>?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by moving the generic parameter to the method and doing a unsafe cast which should always succeed after the filter operation.  Here is the complete code.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

interface Item
data class Pen(val name: String) : Item
data class Eraser(val name: String) : Item
data class Ref<out T : Item> (val id: Int, val item: T)

class Container {
    private val seq = AtomicInteger(0)
    private val items: MutableList<Ref<Item>> = mutableListOf()
    fun <T: Item> add(item: T) =  items.add(Ref(seq.incrementAndGet(), item))

    private fun <T: Item> filter(cls: KClass<T>) : List<Ref<T>> = 
                items.filter{cls.isInstance(it.item)}.map{it as Ref<T>}

    fun pens(): List<Ref<Pen>> = filter(Pen::class)

    fun erasers(): List<Ref<Eraser>> = filter(Eraser::class)
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val container = Container()
    container.add(Pen("Pen-1"))
    container.add(Eraser("Eraser-2"))
    container.add(Pen("Pen-3"))
    container.add(Eraser("Eraser-4"))

    container.pens().forEach{println(it)}
    container.erasers().forEach{println(it)}
}
```